Image background color
I tried to change the background of the animated gif on this post to black, as the yellow part, which is the most important of the design, isn't very visible on white.
However, even when using an html img tag, I can't change it as the style attribute isn't allowed.
Any ideas?



I changed the Gif's background to black in Photoshop

Yeah, I guess that's the easiest solution, thanks.
